# How work the jar located inside the /libs subfolder of an aar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, aar

Inside some `aar` archives their is a `libs` subfolder with some `.jar` in it. What the purpose of those jars? why they are not merged in the classes.jar? If I add the `aar` as a dependency of my android project, how the jar inside the `libs` subfolder will be included in the final `apk`?

Comment: I've never seen that myself but I guess those are dynamically linked JARs, loaded at runtime. If so they will be included the same way in the apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JARs in the `libs` directory of an AAR are dynamically linked during runtime. Exactly like the JAR files you would provide in the `libs` directory of your project.

As you may note, the content of an AAR file is similar to the structure of an Android application project -- at minimum a manifest file, and further (optional) files and directories. You may find resources (`res` and/or `assets`), libraries (native ones in `lib`, JARs in `libs`) and so on. Not every AAR files does even contain a `classes.jar`, as some of theme are only intended to deliver additional `res` content. That can often be found in compat-AARs.

Basically, during the APK building process one simple thing is made with an AAR file which has been included into the project. It will be unzipped and its files and directories are merged -- at least logically, not necessarily physically -- with their corresponding counterparts in the project. So in your case, the JAR files in the AAR's `libs` directory are added to the `libs` directory of your project, where you keep the Java libraries you want to link dynamically during application runtime.

Apart from that the APK building process runs as usual.

In short -- An AAR is a ZIP whose content is merged into the project it was added to.